# How to Remove Trailing Zeroes from a datetime column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in a SQL Server database of datatype `DATETIME`.

Currently the value is in this format: 2054-12-31T00:00:00.0000000

I want to convert this column values into this format : 2054-12-31T00:00:00

This conversion of value should happen while I select the column in `SELECT` query statement at run time

Comment: "Currently the value is in the current format:" - No, It's not. You said it's a datetime column. if you just want a date , cast to date

Answer (score 4):

`DATETIME` as stored in SQL Server **doesn't** have any "format" associated with it - it's stored as a binary, 8 byte value.

In order to convert that binary value into a human-readable format, you need to check out the different styles for `CONVERT`ing a `DATETIME` column into a string representation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

You're probably looking for style #126 - so you can use this in your `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), YourDateTimeColumn, 126)
```

and that should do it

Comment: @SrujanK.N. If an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: Zohar Peled I am facing issue while clicking on the accept option.That is why i had to comment below stating the issue is resolved